# orientdb only update field if null

Tags: orientdb

I am trying to find a way to run an update query with orientdb where I update multiple properties. I will have two properties on an edge, one called acknowledged_at and one called read_at. The acknowledged_at field can get updated prior to the read_at getting updated. However I want to make sure that when I update all of the read_at fields, that I also ensure that any acknowledged_at fields get updated with the current timestamp as well (if they weren't previously set).

My use case for this is having facebook like notifications. A user can acknowledge a notification but not read it at that time. But if they click a read_all button, or decide to "read" just that notification later, then I want to make sure I am also updating the acknowledged_at property (if it is null).

Is there any way to do a case statement type update on the acknowledged_at field to only update if null?

UPDATE: Just to make it more clear, I always want to update the read_at field but only want to update the acknowledged_at field if it is null. If it was previously acknowledged I want that value to remain.

```
UPDATE EDGE received SET read_at = '#{DateTime.now}', acknowledged_at = '#{DateTime.now}' WHERE out.employeeId = '#{employeeId}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>UPDATE EDGE received SET ... WHERE acknowledged_at IS NULL</del>

**UDPATE**

this works for me

```
update edge received set read_at = "2017-06-23 19:29:00",acknowledged_at=ifnull(acknowledged_at, "2017-06-23 19:29:00") WHERE out.employeeId = 'A002'
```

ref. https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/SQL-Functions.html

Comment: In my scenario above I will always want to update the read_at field, but only update acknowledged_at if the value was null. In my scenario it is possible to have acknowledged a notification, but not read it. So the update of acknowledge will be conditional to if the value is null while read_at is always getting updated.

Comment: @DavidBodenschatz Hi. I've updated the answer. Now should work

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (or variation)

```
UPDATE... SET read_at = IF(read_at > 0, read_at, '#{DateTime.now}')
```

Comment: I tried the following but it fails.  
  
`UPDATE EDGE received SET read_at = '2017-06-21 16:20:00', acknowledged_at = IF(acknowledged_at > 0, acknowledged_at, '2017-06-21 16:20:00') WHERE key = '24'`

Comment: try: `IF(acknowledged_at IS NULL`. If fails you must split query, one by each column. Optionally you can send is as bulk by SQL batch: https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/SQL-batch.html